# Loop function in /bin/x11

Tags: 11.10, x11, x11-forwarding

There is a quest about `/bin/x11/` in Ubuntu 11.10.

X11 generate a loop, while a second X11 map is also in it, but it is not possible to delete or change the inbound X11 map within X11.

With regards Ad Verlijsdonk

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to ask [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63696/ubuntu-resolution-issue-causing-login-screen-loop/63697), try:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg`