# Login returns to login screen

Tags: xorg, login, lightdm, gdm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu - resolution issue causing login screen loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63696/ubuntu-resolution-issue-causing-login-screen-loop)

So, after much googling and searching this very site, I've seem to have encountered another problem.

During the upgrade, when asked to use new configuration files or keep my locally modified ones, I told the upgrade to use the new, which I believe is my mistake. I have no idea as how to undo it.

This, I think, has lead to the problem of me not being able to login. I created a secondary user account, and for awhile I could login to that one, but now I can only login via GUI as guest. I can Ctrl Alt F1 to terminal and login that way, but I cannot get in via GUI, no matter which desktop option I use. I've tried sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm and sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm, to no avail. I've also tried ps ax | grep lightdm, sudo apt-get clean/purge/autoremove etc., and sudo stop lightdm, sudo Xorg -configure (which I have no idea on what to edit) then sudo start lightdm, which brings up an error of it not being able to start. When I do try to login, whether I have it set to automatically login, enter my password and hit enter or click on the >, it goes to a black screen with some text that appears really quick and then returns to the login screen.

EDIT:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-24-generic i686). 


Output of ls -l /home: 
total 8
dr-x ------ 4 phil 4096 Apr 30 15:50 phil
drwxr -xr-x 25 phil2 phil2 4096 Apr 30 16:40 phil2
```

I think this is caused because I had tried to comment out some stuff in the above file due to duplicates, and this is the first time this error has come up.

Output of sudo Xorg -configure: 
Fatal server error:
Server is already active for display 0
If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock and start again.
ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log.

I tried adding the Mate Desktop environment (GNOME 2.0), and still cannot login under my primary account or the secondary account I created.

I managed to unencrypt and move my files from my encrypted home folder under my primary account, but that hasn't fixed the problems either. Wiping out and starting fresh really isn't an option.

Acer Aspire One D250 model, Intel Atom N270 1.60 GHz, 1GB RAM, and plenty of hard drive space.

Wiped out my Backtrack 4 installation and partitions, and expanded it for use by my primary (12.04 LTS).