# Ubuntu 12.04 login returns me to login manager, how to diagnose?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, lightdm, login-screen

This started with me adding a graphics card to my system.  When I booted up, ubuntu complained that the graphics config had changed, and gave me a terminal session.  I copied /etc/X11/xorg.conf.failsafe to xorg.conf, and that gave me the standard graphical login manager.

Nw, when I try to log in the screen goes blank for a second, then returns me to the login manager.  It tells me when I give it a deliberately bad password, so I know I'm authenticating.  When I go across to a virtual terminal, I find that nothing in my homedir has been modified, except for ~/.dmrc if I've tried a different login mode. rAs a result, my usual resort of consulting ~/.xsession-errors is unavailable.

Other accounts like "Guest Session" are able to log in without problems, just mine fails.  I have tried moving my ~/.xsession and ~/.xsessionrc to ~/xsession{,.rc}.bak, no effect.  I've looked at /var/log/{syslog,auth.log,kern.log,Xorg.0.log}, and nothing interesting appears there when I try to log in...  I've tried all the suggestions in the following earlier questions:

[Login returns to login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128637/login-returns-to-login-screen)
  [Where should I look to diagnose login freezing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489888/where-should-i-look-to-diagnose-login-freezing)
  [Can't log in to ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139528/cant-log-in-to-ubuntu-12-04)

What else can I try to diagnose this?

I think for now, I am going to work from a different account, but that is going to be a bit of a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to delete the ~/.Xauthority file, as in [this case](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1835833&p=11204011#post11204011).